# Fixed header to static in a particular site

Tags: php, html, css

First let me say that I basically have no knowledge in HTML or CSS, I just like to mess around. 
Second I hate fixed headers which seems to be the "new rule" out there, especially in news and shopping sites. So I use Stylish in Firefox to make headers static, especially in sites with ridiculously large headers, which I found it to be fairly easy in most cases. For example [for this site](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5401#ov) 
I use

```
@-moz-document domain('gigabyte.com') {
    #div_main {
        position: static !important;
    }
}
```

I have done similar things to all sites I visit often and have that "waste of space" header, but I can't get it to work [for this site](http://www.coolermaster.com/cooling/cpu-air-cooler/v6gt/). Is it possible to change it with Stylish or any other way for that matter?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What text editor are you using? because im using notepad++ and I'm basically create a header file ad just call that at the top of the html code for example:

HEADER.PHP file

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="login" style="width:101%;">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
    Password: <input class="align" style="margin-left:3px;" type="password" name="pword"><br>
    <input class="button" type="button" onclick = "location.href = 'registration.php'" name="signin" value="Sign In">
    <a href = "registration.php"><input  class="button" type="button" name="register" value="Sign Up"></a>
    <center>
    <img src = "img/LOGO.jpg" style = "height: 80px; margin-top: -80px; width: 510px;">
    </center>
</div>

<center>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "location.href = 'welcome.php'"><a href="welcome.php">Welcome</a></button></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "location.href = 'hotel.php'"><a href="hotel.php">Hotel</a></button></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "location.href = 'room.php'"><a href="Room.php">Rooms</a></button></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "location.href = 'contactus.php'"><a href="contactUs.php">Contact Us</a></button></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li><button onclick = "location.href = 'gallery.php'"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

And i use this PHP code to call that file to my other pages:

```
<?php
    include('templates/header.php');
?>
```

My header just stays at the top of the page i don't know if i understand what you want to happen but this is my guess hope it helps FYI im just a newbie :)